# Select conditional boolean value across multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three simplified tables shown below:

[image]

What I'm trying to do is select a custom, boolean value from Table A if the **ITEM AND CUSTOMER** attached to the ID have a **VALUE** from Table C & B that match each other.

My current query is below to demonstrate what I'm trying to do:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID, 
            CUSTOMER, 
            ITEM, 
            CASE WHEN B.VALUE = C.VALUE THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS 'VALUEMATCH'
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B
ON A.CUSTOMER = B.CUSTOMER
LEFT JOIN C
ON A.ITEM = C.ITEM
```

... and the result query for ID = 1 and Item1 (as an example) is:

[image]

... and I understand why I'm getting it but I can't see a clear way of fixing it, or even if I can do what I'm trying to do this way?

The result I am looking for is described below:

[image]

Comment: but your issue is because the same customer have two different values in table B

Comment: Please don't post sample data as an image, the volunteers here can't use it. Provide the data as `text`. Or, even better, as `CREATE` and `INSERT` statements.

Comment: @Larnu My apologies.  That makes a lot more sense, thank you for the advice and heads up.  I'll work to update my post!

Comment: @Larnu or both...I mean, the images in this question help to get a better understanding of the data

Comment: @Lamak Right.  I don't see any way around it - so if the answer is "You just can't do it like that" then good to know.  I'm just trying to find SOME way to do it this way.

Comment: Explain the logic that should be followed to produce only one row for Customer 12345 & Item1.   What if the same Item appears more than once in `Table C`?   You may have simplified your table too much, because there are multiple ways of getting your desired result, but they may not do what you actually want with your real data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do :

```
SELECT a.*, (case when exists (select 1
                               from b inner join 
                                    c
                                    on b.value = c.value
                               where b.customer = a.customer and 
                                     c.item = a.item
                              ) 
                  then 1 else 0
             end) as valuematch
FROM a;
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `exists`:

```
select a.*,
       (case when exists (select 1
                          from b join
                               c
                               on b.value = c.value
                          where b.customer = a.customer and c.item = a.item
                         ) 
              then 1 else 0
         end) as valuematch
from a;
```

Comment: Sorry, Yogesh beat you by 2 minutes... thank you for your help! :)

Comment: @gonzzz. . . As of now correct, but he has posted other solution before this one.

Comment: @gonzzz . . . This answer was posted at 15:26:06 and Yogesh's at 15:27:33.  So this was about a minute and a half earlier according to the timestamp on the question.   I honestly do not remember if there was an edit within the first five minutes (after that StackOverflow keeps track of edit times).

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the other answers, looks like you could take your existing query, put a MAX function on `ValueMatch` and GROUP BY the other three columns.

This would be the code:

```
SELECT  ID, 
        CUSTOMER, 
        ITEM, 
        MAX(CASE WHEN B.VALUE = C.VALUE THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS VALUEMATCH
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B
    ON A.CUSTOMER = B.CUSTOMER
LEFT JOIN C
    ON A.ITEM = C.ITEM
GROUP BY ID, 
         CUSTOMER, 
         ITEM
;
```

Comment: I like this one better, sounds to me like it would have better performance (hope you don't mind that I edited your answer)